# Category.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: categories is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to display Categories and Category Children in the admin dashboard and the terminal gives no error. But the page consol renders Category.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: categories is not iterable
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: categories is not iterable

**Category Component:**

```
import React, { useEffect ,useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col ,Modal ,Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout/Layout'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getAllCategory } from '../../actions'
import Input from '../../components/UI/Input/Input'
import {addCategory} from '../../actions/category.actions'





const Category = () => {
    const category = useSelector(state => state.category)
    const [categoryName , setCategoryName] =useState('')
    const [parentCategoryId , setParentCategoryId] =useState('')
    const [categoryImage , setCategoryImage] =useState('')




    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Category.js')
        dispatch(getAllCategory())
    }, [])

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => {

        const form = new FormData()
        // const cat ={
        //     categoryName,
        //     parentCategoryId,
        //     categoryImage
        // }

        form.append('name',categoryName)
        form.append('parentId',parentCategoryId)
        form.append('categoryImage',categoryImage)
        dispatch(addCategory(form))



        // console.log('cat',cat)

        setShow(false);
    }
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const renderCategories = (categories) => {
        let myCategories = []
        for (let category of categories) {
            myCategories.push(
                <li key={Math.random()}>
                    {category.name}
                    {category.children.length > 0 ? (<ul>{renderCategories(category.children)}</ul>) : null}
                </li>
            )
        }
        return myCategories;
    }



    const createCategoryList=(categories,options=[])=>{
        for(let category of categories) {
            options.push({value: category._id , name: category.name})
            if(category.children.length > 0){
                createCategoryList(category.children, options)
            }
        }
        return options;
    }


    const handelCategoryImage =(e)=>{
        setCategoryImage(e.target.files[0])
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Layout sidebar>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={12}>
                            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                                <h3>Category</h3>
                                <button onClick={handleShow}>Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={12}>
                            <ul>
                                {renderCategories(category.categories)}
                            </ul>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>

                <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Add New Category</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Input
                            value={categoryName}
                            placeholder={'Category Name'}
                            onChange={(e)=>setCategoryName(e.target.value)}
                        />

                        <select className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>setParentCategoryId(e.target.value)} value={parentCategoryId}>
                            <option>Select Category</option>
                            {
                                createCategoryList(category.categories).map(option =>
                                    <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>)
                            }
                        </select>
                        <input type='file' name='categoryImage' onChange={handelCategoryImage}/>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                            Save Changes
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </Layout>
        </>
    );
};

export default Category;
```

**Category.action.js**

```
import axios from "axios"
import axiosInstance from "../helpers/axios"
import {categoryConstants} from './constants'
export const getAllCategory =()=>{
    return async dispatch => {

        dispatch({type: categoryConstants.GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_REQUEST})

        const res =await axios.get('http://localhost:2000/api/category/getcategory')
        console.log("res",res)
        if(res.status === 200) {
            // const {categoryList} = res.data
            // console.log("categoryList",categoryList)
            dispatch({ 
                type:categoryConstants.GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
                payload: {category:res.data.category}
            })
        }else{
            dispatch({
                type: categoryConstants.GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_FAILURE,
                payload: {error: res.data.error}
            })
        }
    }
}


export const addCategory =(form) => {
    const token =window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: categoryConstants.ADD_NEW_CATEGORY_REQUEST})
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:2000/api/category/create',form,{headers:{
            'Authorization':token ? `Bearer ${token}` :''
        }})
        if(res.status === 200){
            dispatch({
                type: categoryConstants.ADD_NEW_CATEGORY_SUCCESS,
                payload:res.data.category
            })
        }else{
            dispatch({
                type: categoryConstants.ADD_NEW_CATEGORY_FAILURE,
                payload:res.data.error
            })
        }
        console.log("res", res)
    }
}
```

**category.reducer.js**

```
import {categoryConstants} from '../actions/constants'
const initState ={
    categories:[],
    loading:false,
    error:null,
}

const buildNewCategories =(categories,category)=>{
    let myCategories=[]
    for(let cat of categories){
        myCategories.push({
            ...cat,
            children: cat.children && cat.children.length > 0 ? buildNewCategories(cat.children,category):[]
        })
    }

    return myCategories;
}


export default (state = initState , action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case categoryConstants.GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
            state={
                ...state,
                categories: action.payload.categories
            }
            break;
        case categoryConstants.ADD_NEW_CATEGORY_REQUEST:
            state={
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            }
            break;
        case categoryConstants.ADD_NEW_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
            const updatedCategories=buildNewCategories(state.categories, action.payload.category)
            console.log('updated categoires', updatedCategories);
                state={
                    ...state,
                    categories:updatedCategories,
                    loading: false,
                }
                break;
        case categoryConstants.ADD_NEW_CATEGORY_FAILURE:
            state={
                ...initState,
            }
            break;

    }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `const category = useSelector(state => state.category)` to get category , you was not sure whether or not `category` has been fetched successfully yet ( focus on the calling `getAllCategory()` on your `useEffect` ).

You just need to check before iterate `categories` , and some refactor your code like this is fine:

```
const renderCategories = (categories) => {
        if(!Array.isArray(categories)) return null
        return categories.map((category, i) => (
               <li key={`category-${i}`}>
                    {category.name}
                    {Array.isArray(category.children) && category.children.length > 0 ? (
                          <ul>{renderCategories(category.children)}</ul>
                     ) : null}
                </li>) 
        )
}
```

Also you can wrap your function `renderCategories` with useCallback to make more effective

```
import { useCallback } from 'react'

const renderCategories = useCallback((categories) => {
            if(!Array.isArray(categories)) return null
            return categories.map((category, i) => (
                   <li key={`category-${i}`}>
                        {category.name}
                        {Array.isArray(category.children) && category.children.length > 0 ? (
                              <ul>{renderCategories(category.children)}</ul>
                         ) : null}
                    </li>) 
            )
    }, [])
```